# Fonte personalizada no html/css não funciona

Tags: html, css, html5, css-font-face, font

Estou tentando inserir uma fonte não padrão no meu `html`, mas ela não está funcionando. Baixei a fonte e coloquei numa pasta `/font` dentro da pasta `css`. Segue o código:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: sans-pro;
    src: url("/font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
}

#header1 {
  font-family: sans-pro;
  color: red;
}
```

estou usando windows7 e wampserver.

segue a localização da fonte:
[image: Localização das fontes dentro da pasta "css/font"]

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor chamar a fonte via Google Api?

Exemplo no css:

```
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
    </style>
```

Exemplo no html dentro da tag `<head>`:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

Para usar:

```
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

Você pode customiza-la como quiser pelo [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?selection.family=Source%20Sans%20Pro)

Answer (score 0):

```
src: url("font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
```

ou assim

```
src: url("./font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
```

Comment: tentei ambas as sugestões, mas nenhum sucesso.

Comment: @FernandoWilliam tenta sem as aspas assim `src: url(font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);`

Comment: Nada feito, amigo!

Comment: Qual navegador?
Faz assim (é cross-browser):
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sans-pro';
    src:url(font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'); /*Para navegadores Internet Explorer*/
    src: local("sans-pro"), url(font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

A única coisa que tu precisa fazer é uma cópia da fonte ttf em formato eot.
Use esse site pra isso: https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: André, eu estou usando o chrome, mas após sua dica converti a fonte no site indicado, utilizei o código sugerido, testei também no IE e Mozilla mas nada aconteceu. Pensei que pudesse existir algum erro no meu código, mas quando testo com outra fonte (cursive,arial, times...) funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu acho que o problema **não é relacionado com a localização da fonte**, porque senão este código:

```
src: url("font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
```

Já mencionado acima iria funcionar.
Eu acho que o problema está relacionado no **bloqueio do acesso a esse ficheiro** através do servidor, por acaso não mexeu nas páginas de bloqueio???

Também experimente acessar ao ficheiro da ttf pelo browser para verificar esse tipo de erro exemplo:

```
localhost/CodeNumberOne/css/font/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazer funcionar com a fonte instalada no PC, porém foi necessário colocar o código na página do css e na página principal. Veja só:

---

NO HTML:

```
<head>

    <title> :: TEXTO EM CSS ::</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css_style/h12_texto_css.css" type="text/css" 
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IMPORTANDO DE DENTRO DO PRÓPRIO PC! -->
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Tiza';
            src: url('fonts/tiza.eot');
            src: url('fonts/tiza.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('fonts/tiza.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('fonts/tiza.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('fonts/tiza.svg#Tiza') format('svg');  
        }
    </style>


    <!-- IMPORTANDO DA API DO GOOLE OUTRAS FONTE - VEJA EM 
    http://fonts.google.com -->

    <style> /* mantenha dessa forma, mesmo que o editor sinalizee erro! */
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One');
    </style>

</head>
```

---

NO CSS:
[image: veja como fica no CSS]

---

> > > Aí então, no CSS basta chamar as fontes normalmente. Relmente pelo Google API é muitoooooo mais simples! Muito mesmo! Entretanto, você fica na dependência do servidor deles (embora eu ache que NUNCA vá dar problema hehehe).